# Шаблонная оболочка для функции

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

Нужна статическая оболочка вокруг функции, для разнесения этой самой функции по разным адресам.. Разумной реализацией показался следующий код:

```
void MyFunc()
{
    cout << "message" << endl;
}

template<typename Func, Func func, typename... Args>
void FuncShell(Args... args)
{
    func(args...);
}

int main(void)
{
    cout << (size_t)&MyFunc << endl;
    cout << (size_t)&FuncShell<decltype(MyFunc), MyFunc>() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Но как и ожидалось, не всё так просто. Компилятор отказывается принимать "void()" в качестве аргумента шаблона. Что делать?

Comment: Эээ, а что означает «для разнесения этой самой функции по разным адресам»?

Comment: Чтобы одна и та же статическая функция была доступна по 2м разным адресам. Посмотрите на функцию main, думаю там более ясно сформулирована мысль.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void MyFunc()
{
    cout << "message" << endl;
}

template<typename Func, Func* func, typename... Args>
void FuncShell(Args... args)
{
    func(args...);
}

int main()
{
    FuncShell<decltype(MyFunc), &MyFunc>();
    cout << (size_t)(&FuncShell<decltype(MyFunc), &MyFunc>);
    return 0;
}
```

http://ideone.com/JqsOTS

---

Разъяснение: функция не есть значение, и таким образом не может быть параметром-значением шаблона. А вот указатель на функцию — вполне.

Comment: благодарю, то что нужно.

Comment: @Dylan993: Пожалуйста!